# Samba, PAM and encrypted home directory

Tags: ssh, login, samba, encryption, ecryptfs

So, I have an encrypted home, PAM usually unwraps the passphrase via `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`. This works fine for SSHD sessions, however when I open up a samba session, though it logs in, it doesn't unwrap the password:

```
Signature not found in user keyring
Perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'
```

I'm unsure why this isn't triggering, as the following are present:

```
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth    optional pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap

/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
session optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap

/etc/pam.d/samba
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

Any ideas?